# Add pvalue bracket with stat_pvalue_manual on geom_bar

Tags: r, ggplot2, p-value

I wouldl like to use stat_pvalue_manual in order to add pvalue on my geom barplot.
I have these following dataset and stat.table (created to reproduce my data).
I can add the pvalue, but the bracket does not appear as it should.
Can you help me to see what is wrong in my code.

[image]

```
 # data
######################### 

Data_test=structure(list(PE = c(87, 32, 15, 87, 43, 65, 76, 25), 
                         BU = c("A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A1", "A2", "A3", "A4"), 
                         PH = c("NAF", "NAF","NAF", "NAF", "AF", "AF", "AF", "AF")), 
                   class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), 
                   row.names = c(NA, -8L), 
                   groups = structure(list(BU = c("A1","A1", "A2", "A2", "A3", "A3","A4", "A4"), 
                   PH = c("AF","NAF", "AF", "NAF", "AF", "NAF","AF", "NAF"), .rows = structure(list(5L, 1L, 6L, 2L, 7L, 3L, 8L, 4L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               ), row.names = c(NA, -8L), .drop = TRUE))

 # stat table
######################### 

Stat_test= structure(list(group1 = c("NAF", "NAF", "NAF", 
                          "NAF"), group2 = c("AF", "AF", "AF", 
                                                      "AF"), PE = c(65, 87, 87, 
                                                                            43), 
                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                                                         p = c(0.7654, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                       0.456, 0.789, 0.003),  BU = c("A1", "A2", "A3", "A4")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  -4L))

# Graph
#########################  

library(ggpubr)
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(Data_test, aes(x=BU, y=PE)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill=PH), stat="identity", position=position_dodge(), color="black") +
  stat_pvalue_manual(Stat_test, y.position = 100, size=4,
                     label = "p", inherit.aes = FALSE, remove.bracket = FALSE,  x="BU", 
                     tip.length = 0.02, bracket.size = 4, ) +
  ylim(c(0,100))
```

```
> Data_test
# A tibble: 8 × 3
# Groups:   BU, PH [8]
     PE BU    PH   
  <dbl> <chr> <chr>
1    87 A1    NAF  
2    32 A2    NAF  
3    15 A3    NAF  
4    87 A4    NAF  
5    43 A1    AF   
6    65 A2    AF   
7    76 A3    AF   
8    25 A4    AF

> Stat_test
  group1 group2 PE      p BU ypos
1    NAF     AF 65 0.7654 A1  100
2    NAF     AF 87 0.4560 A2  100
3    NAF     AF 87 0.7890 A3  100
4    NAF     AF 43 0.0030 A4  100
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be an easier way, but adding `xmin` and `xmax` values to your `Stat_test` data frame will do the trick:

```r
ggplot(Data_test, aes(x = BU, y = PE)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = PH), position = position_dodge(), color = "black") +
  stat_pvalue_manual(Stat_test %>% 
                       mutate(xmin = 1:4 -0.2, xmax = 1:4 + 0.2), 
                     y.position = 100, size = 4, label = "p", 
                     tip.length = 0.02, bracket.size = 0.8) +
  ylim(c(0, 100)
```

[image]

Comment: It works well also on similar data with same number of test. I would like to know how did you compute the xmin and x max. I wanted to apply this solution on another dataset where I have now 5 categories in PH. As I have now 40 row in my table i  used mutate(xmin = 1:40 -0.2, xmax = 1:40 + 0.2) but this is not working..

Comment: @Av65 in a plot with categorical x axis, the x axis labels are actually sited at integer values. The x values would therefore be equivalent to `as.numeric(as.factor(Data_test$BU))`. The xmin values would be this number minus 0.2, and the xmax values would be the x value +0.2

Comment: Ok thank you, I understood. I will try to adapt this code for this other situation. I have some ideas, hope it will work.